# regexp find for Chinese unicode character

Tags: go, unicode

i have code like this

```
re, err = regexp.Compile(`\p{Han}*`)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
s := "foo中文哦woqu"
fmt.Println(re.FindString(s))
```

but it print empty.

and then i change `\p{Han}*` to `\p{Han}+`, it display's 中文哦.

change `\p{Han}*` to `\p{Han}?`, it print empty.

I find the document like this:

- x*   zero or more x, prefer more
- x+   one or more x, prefer more
- x?   zero or one x, prefer one

so i expect my print is:

- `\p{Han}*` print 中文哦
- `\p{Han}+` print 中文哦
- `\p{Han}?` print 中

could someone tell me what happened?

Comment: if you want to find the character just use `{Han}` without anything

Comment: re, err = regexp.Compile(\`{Han}\`)
like this? it print empty too.

Comment: like this `regexp.Compile(\`\p{Han}\`)`

Comment: This will only match one character. I want to match more.

Answer (score 4):

As the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindString) say (emphasis added):

> FindString returns a string holding the text of the leftmost match in s of the regular expression. If there is no match, the return value is an empty string, **but it will also be empty if the regular expression successfully matches an empty string.** Use FindStringIndex or FindStringSubmatch if it is necessary to distinguish these cases.

`\p{Han}*` matches an empty string. You can also see that by using `FindAllString`:

```
fmt.Printf("%q", re.FindAllString(s, -1))
// Prints ["" "" "" "中文哦" "" "" "" ""]
```

You can use `\p{Han}+` which doesn't match an empty string.

Comment: I think i understand what happened:because * and ? also match empty  string, so find method print  first matched string which is empty, thanks for  reply.